# Convention for test method names in Python

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I have a test that tests class `AbbreviationGenerator`. Class names should use camel case, while method names should be lower case. Should I then name the test method `test_AbbreviationGenerator` or `test_abbreviation_generator`?

Comment: `test_abbreviation_generator` – see [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the test is a method (as you say) then it's associated with a class, let's say the class is named *AbbreviationGeneratorTest*. Then you can simply name the method *run*.